# Can ElasticSearch Be Used To Index and Query Private (Not Publicly Exposed) Data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, content-management-system

I'm considering implementing Elasticsearch into a Content Management System (CMS) web app built using Ruby on Rails. However, since the app requires user account creation, none of the data is publicly exposed. When I'm indexing and quering this private data, will I be able to use Elasticsearch?

Comment: ES has no notion of security. You should ideally have a layer between your ruby application and ES if you want to enforce authorization/authentication. You should try not to expose your ES endpoint if your goal is to keep the data private. Instead expose the secure layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although Elasticsearch does not consider security at all, so you would need to handle this via your data access layer.